# AC Dripping A LOT after a rain

Tags: air-conditioning

When I turn on my window AC after a rainfall, water pours out causing a problem on a terrace below - rain seems to be collecting. I've seen these magnetic foam AC drip cushions meant to reduce noise from ACs above. Can I use it on mine to prevent rain from collecting inside the AC? Is it safe to use these - for any reason - since they cover the top vents of the AC?

Comment: Do not cover those two vents. Can you give us more information on the AC? The ones I use to use collected water in the bottom which had a drain outlet. Check to see if yours does. You might have a high efficiency one that blows the condensate through the condenser and no drain.

Comment: Is your AC tilted correctly???   They have to be tilted at a manufacturer specified angle to ensure the water drains out.

Comment: Re @Gil's advise... I have a couple newer "high efficiency" ones like he describes... Mine had rubber plugs I could remove to drain if I wanted to bypass that.  See if yours does.  I did remove the plugs....

Comment: Thanks, everyone! I tried removing the plug and it still drips. The manual says to have it level or slightly tilted out - it's level. I think I might just give up and get a portable AC. I know they are less efficient, but I've been dealing with the drip not only with this AC (which didn't drip last year) but the one before it.

Comment: Janine a portable inside will have water collection jug or tray and they shutdown when full.  part of cooling the air is dehumidification. The same thing happens to a glass of ice water the moisture on the outside is moisture collecting on the cold glass the same happens in the evaporator but it has a much larger surface area

Comment: Thanks, Ed! Yes, I've researched them. Still seems like the best solution...other than this neighbor moving!  Honestly, there's little she doesn't complain about! :)

Answer (score 2):

Accumulation of water in the condensing coil is common in outdoor coils you can make a shield to reduce the moisture that may collect there but this is only part of the problem.

After a rain the humidity increases and a lot of moisture is collected on the evaporator coil.

The moisture from the evaporator is usually the majority of the water dripping I found attaching a heavy string at the drain long enough the downstairs neighbor was able to put the string to the side (not dripping in their door way) this made for happy/ friendly neighbors ,,  ok with the exception of water balloons one evening after work but the string worked quite well.

Comment: Thank you! With the previous AC, it started when it got old and I hooked up a funnel and tubing - sort of like your string idea. Got this new one, and, after a year, the same thing started...